# Programatically bind a single spring cloud function to several inputs

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

In my application all incoming messages sit in a number of message broker topics. What I would like to have is a Spring cloud function whose input is bound to all of these topics, so that messages from any topic would be processed by that cloud function. I would also like to add more binding like this in runtime, so when a new topic is added by some third-party, and messages start to be put there, the same cloud function would receive those messages, too.

Any examples of how to programatically manage the bindings of spring cloud functions to [multiple] spring cloud stream destinations would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 1):

The `...destination` property can contain a list of [destinations delimited by coma](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_common_binding_properties).

As far as adding more destinations dynamically on the consumer side unfortunately s-c-stream was not designed for this type of use cases. You can probably have some external monitor to watch for those things and change configuration and restart app.

Comment: Ok, then let me simplify the problem statement a bit. What if I have the list of destination names to subscribe persisted somewhere in a db, and my goal is to have a "one-to-many" binding between my cloud function and each one of these destinations when my app starts up? So basically I'm ok to drop the "runtime updates" requirement...

Comment: Then you may want to consider adding another spring-cloud project to your stack which is specifically designed to externalize configuration - [Spring Cloud Config](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config)